# Microwind does not create my equation in compile

Tags: layer, mask, vlsi

I user microwind and try to build the mask from the compile one line choice but it wont let me the equation simplified is ~A&(~B|~C|D)

Answer (score 0):

Try bisecting the equation into small parts and then try.

**part1**
Get a layout of only `~B | ~C | D` . save that as *module1*

**part2**
Import *module1* and go for its implementation for `~A & *module1*`

Follow the [D flip Flop tutorial](http://www.microwind.me/2009/12/design-and-layout-of-d-flip-flop-using.html) and post the efforts done.